Plotly Dash - AG GRID View is very small
My problem is that the ag grid table is very short. I tried many things I couldn’t resize it. I want it to use the whole screen in a responsive way.
# dashboard/dash_apps/aggrid.py

from dash import html
import dash_ag_grid as dag
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash
from dashboard.views import get_latest_data
from dashboard.config_views.config import column_settings

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]

app = DjangoDash("AGGrid", external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = get_latest_data()


column_defs = ..

app.layout = (
    dag.AgGrid(
        id="ag-grid",
        columnDefs=column_defs,
        rowData=df.to_dict("records"),
        defaultColDef={
            "filter": True,
            "sortable": True,
            "resizable": True,
        },
        dashGridOptions={
            "domLayout": "autoHeight",
            "pagination": True,  # Aktiviert die Paginierung
            "paginationPageSize": 50,
        },  # Setzt die Anzahl der Zeilen pro Seite auf 50},
    ),
)


<!-- dashboard/templates/dashboard/base.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>{% block title %}Meine Django App{% endblock %}</title>
        {% load static %}

        <!-- Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
            #app {
                height: 100%;
            }
            main {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="app" class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
        
        <header class="mb-4">
            <!-- Navigation -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light mb-4">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                   ....
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <main class="flex-grow-1">
            {% block content %}
            <!-- Der spezifische Inhalt wird hier eingefügt -->
            {% endblock %}
        </main>

        <footer class="text-center mt-4">
            <p>&copy; 2023 Meine Django App</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (für Bootstrap-Abhängigkeiten) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle mit Popper.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

<!-- dashboard/templates/dashboard/aggrid.html -->
{% extends 'dashboard/base.html' %}
{% load plotly_dash %}

{% block title %}
  Dash AG Grid View
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% plotly_app name="AGGrid" %}
{% endblock %}

I tried many things, such as trying to resize it in the aggrid.html or testing other bootstrap classes or editing the div in the aggrid.py.
I have a base html which I also showed. I hope somebody can help.
EDIT:
Solution was the aggrid.html
The iframe was limited.
{% plotly_app name="AGGrid" %} --> {% plotly_app name="AGGrid" height="85vh"%}


    children=[
        html.Div(
            id="ag-grid-container", 
            style={"height": "600px", "width": "100%"}  # Set height and width
        ),
    ]
)````


Can you post the full code? I tried it and it does not work..
Thanks in advance. @Ahmad Raza

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
